# AdvancedFilter macro runs slower with AutoFilter off

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I've been trying to understand a Macro that a coworker found somewhere online for filtering a set of data based on selected criteria. Part of the code is an IF statement checking to see if AutoFilterMode is off, then toggling it on if it is found to be off, as so

```
'Turn on filter if not already turned on
If Sheets("ORDER DATA").AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter
```

The very next line uses .AdvancedFilter to filter the data based on the selected criteria (a range referred to as filter)

```
rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=filter, Unique:=True
```

I'm relatively OCD about wanting to keep things cleaned up in my code so I was thinking that I'd get rid of the first statement as it didn't seem necessary. What I've found since eliminating it is that the filtering process takes significantly longer to run if the first statement is eliminated.

I've searched high and low online but haven't been able to find what the relationship between AutoFilter and AdvancedFilter is.

So my question is this: why does the AdvancedFilter take so much longer to run when the AutoFilter isn't first turned on?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, Excel keeps some kind of cache when `Autofilter` is on and then `AdvancedFilter` use that cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume that you have this at the top of your code? If not, add it and see if that fixes it. Don't forget to have the reset options at the bottom.

```
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
'your code goes here
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

As I said, I assume that was there and didn't resolve it, so that being said... Usually, with autofilter and advancedfilter weirdness it is something with the data. So there are a number of things I go through when I need to tweak a sheet. Have you tried all these?

First, create a new workbook, copy all your data in the old workbook and paste values only into the new workbook. Keep as minimal as you can get away with in order for you to still use that macro. IE: if there are buttons and such that you don't need to transfer, dont. If there are extra sheets that aren't needed, don't transfer them either. If you can do values instead of formulas, do values only. But do transfer the entire relevant data set and not just some sample lines so that it is as apples to apples as possible.

If it still runs slow like that then we are definitely looking at some weird situation with the code and it might be the cache thing like litelite proposed. If it works more like you would expect then we know it is either a formatting thing or some other thing messing with it.

Assuming the second to start with as that is usually the issue.
Try each of these on the original data and rerun it. Any order works so whichever is easiest to start with. I usually rerun macros after each change and don't go through doing all of these before running it again so I can know which thing fixed it. Also, not all of these will necessarily apply as I don't know your data. Ignore them if they don't apply.
First make a copy and do these to the copy. If you go through multiples and find a fix, make a copy of the original again and then apply only the last change to the copy and see if it still fixes it.

If you have multiple sheets, make a copy and delete all the extra sheets. Test it on just the minimal amount of sheets you can use. Likewise if you have multiple sheets left, each of the following needs to be done to all of them:

- Copy all non-formula data and paste special/values to get rid of any
  weird formatting/etc.
- Unhide all rows.
- Delete all comments.
- Delete all conditional formatting.
- Select all, turn on wrap text, then turn off wrap text. (I call this the Microsoft Hokey-Pokey. You put the check-mark in, you take the check-mark out...)
- If you have any forms buttons/objects delete them and see if it is faster.

Finally, how many rows of data are you working with in the data set?